# Update a field based on another field

Tags: formula-field

I have a picklist field with values like Logged, Scoping, Scheduling.

I want a formula field to auto-update based on the picklist field. So if a record has "Logged" in the field, this field should auto-populate to "Next"

CASE(Stage__c,
‘Logged’,’Later’,
‘Scoping’,’Later’,
‘In Progress’,’Now’ ,
‘Closed’,’Released’,
)

CASE(Stage__c, ‘Logged’,’Later’, ‘Scoping’,’Later’, ‘In Progress’,’Now’ , ‘Closed’,’Released’, )

ERROR: Syntax Error

Tried many different ways and still not able to get this to work.

Any help appreciated

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working? Are you getting an error message when you try to save the formula? If you are getting an error, you should _always_ include it in your questions.

Comment: Outside of the obvious (you've specified "Later" for both "Logged" and "Scoping"), it appears that you may be using "smart" quotes, and you have an extra comma after "Released". Formulas can't use "smart" quotes, you need to use single or double (straight) quotes instead.

Comment: Hi Derek - The picklist has 9 values, 3 of which I'd like to return in formula field as 'Now', 3 as 'Later', and 3 as 'Released'.

Comment: There's more to the error than just "syntax error". We need the entire error message, we need _details_ to be able to help you. We can't read your mind, see your screen, or log into your org. The only things we have to go on are what you tell us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a total of an even number of parameters. The first parameter is the value to check against, then pairs of values and outputs, and a final value that is the default value. You currently have nine parameters; you can't specify a value using `, )`, there must be something there. If you want no output, use the word `null` or an empty string: `, '')`. Note that formulas are not case sensitive, so if you prefer, you can use uppercase as well.

So, to recap, your formula should look like:

```
CASE(
  Stage__c,
  'Logged','Later',
  'Scoping','Later',
  'In Progress','Now',
  'Closed','Released',
  null
)
```

It's much easier to read if you add newlines between the parameters so that they read like case statements do in code, as demonstrated above.

Comment: Thank you so much sfdcfox - done!